# Keras - multi-input model using flow_from_dataframe

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

### **Problem**

I am trying to build a multi-input model in keras using two inputs, image and text. I am using the `flow_from_dataframe` method, passing it a pandas dataframe containing the image-names as well as the respective text (as a vectorized feature-represenation) for each image and the target label/class. As such, the dataframe looks as follows:

```
ID     path                 text-features             label
111    'cat001.jpg'       [0.0, 1.0, 0.0,...]         cat
112    'dog001.jpg'       [1.0, 0.0, 1.0,...]         dog
113    'bunny001.jpg'     [0.0, 1.0, 1.0,...]         bunny
...
```

After constructing my model using the Keras functional API, I feed both inputs into the model like so:

```
model = Model(inputs=[images, text], outputs=output)
```

For the images I use an ImageDataGenerator as suggested in the docs (https://keras.io/preprocessing/image/#flow_from_dataframe) :

```
datagen=ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1./255,validation_split=0.15)

train_generator=datagen.flow_from_dataframe(dataframe=df, directory=data_dir, x_col=path, y_col="label", has_ext=True, class_mode="categorical", target_size=(224,224), batch_size=batch_size,subset="training")

 validation_generator=datagen.flow_from_dataframe(dataframe=df, directory=data_dir, x_col=path, y_col="label", has_ext=True, class_mode="categorical", target_size=(224,224), batch_size=batch_size,subset="validation")
```

So far so good, but now I am stuck on how to feed the text-features within my dataframe to the model as well during training.

### **Question**

How can I modify the `flow_from_dataframe` generator in order to handle the text-feature data in the dataframe as well as the images during training? Also, since I can't find any example of this sort of modification on `flow_from_dataframe` I am wondering if I am approaching this problem wrong i.e. is there any better method of achieving this?

### UPDATE

Meanwhile I've been trying to write my own generator following the guide I found here (https://stanford.edu/~shervine/blog/keras-how-to-generate-data-on-the-fly) and adjusting it to my needs. This is what I came up with:

```
from matplotlib.image import imread


class DataGenerator(keras.utils.Sequence):
    def __init__(self, list_IDs, labels, batch_size=32, dim=(32,32,32), n_channels=1,
                 n_classes=10, shuffle=True):
        #'Initialization'
        self.dim = dim
        self.batch_size = batch_size
        self.labels = labels
        self.list_IDs = list_IDs
        self.n_channels = n_channels
        self.n_classes = n_classes
        self.shuffle = shuffle
        self.on_epoch_end() 

    def on_epoch_end(self):
      #'Updates indexes after each epoch' 
        self.indexes = np.arange(len(self.list_IDs))
        if self.shuffle == True:
            np.random.shuffle(self.indexes)

# method for producing batches of data.
# takes as argument the list of IDs of the target batch
def __data_generation(self, list_IDs_temp):
    #'Generates data containing batch_size samples' # X : (n_samples, *dim, n_channels)
    # Initialization
    X = np.empty((self.batch_size, *self.dim, self.n_channels))
    Xtext = np.empty((self.batch_size, 7576)) 
    y = np.empty((self.batch_size), dtype=int)

    # Generate data
    for i, ID in enumerate(list_IDs_temp):
        # Store sample
        X[i,] = imread('C:/Users/aaron/Desktop/training/'+str(ID)) # <--- all files are in the same DIR
        Xtext[i,] = np.array(total_data[df.path== str(ID)]["text-features"].values) # <--- I look-up the text-features by using the ID as a filter with the path column. This line throws the error. 


        # Store class
        y[i] = self.labels[ID]

    return X, Xtext, keras.utils.to_categorical(y, num_classes=self.n_classes)

def __len__(self):
  #'Denotes the number of batches per epoch'
  return int(np.floor(len(self.list_IDs) / self.batch_size))

# Now, when the batch corresponding to a given index is called, 
# the generator executes the __getitem__ method to generate it.
def __getitem__(self, index):
    #'Generate one batch of data'
    # Generate indexes of the batch
    indexes = self.indexes[index*self.batch_size:(index+1)*self.batch_size]

    # Find list of IDs
    list_IDs_temp = [self.list_IDs[k] for k in indexes]

    # Generate data
    X,Xtext, y = self.__data_generation(list_IDs_temp)

    return X,Xtext, y
```

And I initialize the generator as follows:

```
partition = {}
partition['train'] = X_train.path.values
partition['validation'] = X_test.path.values

from sklearn import preprocessing
le = preprocessing.LabelEncoder()
encoded_labels = le.fit_transform(df.label)

labels = pd.Series(encoded_labels,index=df.path).to_dict()

# Parameters
params = {'dim': (224,224),
          'batch_size': 64,
          'n_classes': 5,
          'n_channels': 3,
          'shuffle': True}


# Generators
training_generator = DataGenerator(partition['train'], labels, **params)
validation_generator = DataGenerator(partition['validation'], labels, **params)
```

Using this generator however throws me an error:

> ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.

caused by the line  `X_text[i,] = np.array(total_data[total_data.bust == str(ID)].text.values)` in my code above. Any suggestion on how to solve this?

Comment: If the data isn't huge enough to occupy the entire RAM, I think it's better to preprocess the dataframe first and save a numpy array with the text features.

Comment: @DanielMöller thanks for your suggestion! I've tried loading it into RAM, however the dataset is too large for my setup :( Now I've been trying to write my own generator but it throws me an error (updated my question)

Comment: I am interested doing exactly the same development. Have you succeeded in your task since you asked the question ?

Comment: Have you solved the problem? I am also facing the same issue. I am also creating siamese network with 3 multiple inputs and I am not able to pass them through ImageDataGenerator specifically flow_from_dataframe().